# Image on top of div-cover-background, resize proportionally

Tags: css

I was trying, and googling and searching, but can not solve very simple scenarion... I have:

```
<div class = "BG">
  <div class = "image"></div>
</div>
```

The background should be centered, and image should be centered. On browser resize, both should resize proportionally to each other.

For the BG class, I have this:

```
 background: url("../img/d_background.jpg");
 width: 100%;
 height: 2160px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center; 
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
```

which makes BG working exactly as I need. But, as for the child image, it always incorrect size and position. Is there any way to make them work in-synch? I tried many different solution, but child image ends up either being cut-off, of being incorrect size.

Comment: Well you should probably start by giving the image a width in percent as well, so that it can adapt to the container width.

Answer (score 0):

you can attribute to your image the object-fit: cover; in your css

your image will take the dimension of his parent.